# Config u-boot for new board error because __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, beagleboard, kbuild

I try some set up config to load u-boot for a new board. My configuration is based on U-boot for Beagle Bone Black. I also follow some changes for new board on https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Mastering-Embedded-Linux-Programming-Second-Edition/blob/master/Chapter03/0001-BSP-for-Nova.patch.
I clone a new u-boot and stand at master branch, after I made config file for new board, I ran make. It has 2 issues:

1. First is about SYS_TEXT_BASE:

> scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
>
> .config:22:warning: symbol value '' invalid for SYS_TEXT_BASE
>
> *
>   * Restart config...
>   *
>   *
>
> - Boot images
>     *
>
> Enable support for Android Boot Images (ANDROID_BOOT_IMAGE) [Y/n/?] y
>
> Support Flattened Image Tree (FIT) [N/y/?] n
>
> Enable support for the legacy image format (IMAGE_FORMAT_LEGACY)
>   [Y/n/?] y
>
> Set up board-specific details in device tree before boot
>   (OF_BOARD_SETUP) [N/y/?] n
>
> Set up system-specific details in device tree before boot
>   (OF_SYSTEM_SETUP) [N/y/?] n
>
> Update the device-tree stdout alias from U-Boot (OF_STDOUT_VIA_ALIAS)
>   [N/y/?] n
>
> Extra Options (DEPRECATED) (SYS_EXTRA_OPTIONS) []
>
> Text Base (SYS_TEXT_BASE) [] (NEW)

Then I search for a SYS_TEXT_BASE and entered a random text base: 0xfff10000. But I think it's not for Beagle Bone.

2. Error **LINUX_ARM_ARCH**

> In file included from ./arch/arm/include/asm/system.h:6:0,
>
> ```
>              from ./arch/arm/include/asm/cache.h:11,
>              from include/net.h:15,
>              from include/common.h:517,
>              from lib/asm-offsets.c:14:
> ```
>
> ./arch/arm/include/asm/barriers.h:32:24: error: operator '>=' has no
>   left operand  #if **LINUX_ARM_ARCH** >= 7
>                           ^~
>
> ./arch/arm/include/asm/barriers.h:36:26: error: operator '==' has no
>   left operand  #elif **LINUX_ARM_ARCH** == 6
>                             ^~
>   Kbuild:43: recipe for target 'lib/asm-offsets.s' failed
>
> make[1]: *** [lib/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
>
> Makefile:1575: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
>
> make: *** [prepare0] Error 2

For the second issue,  this was caused by a Kconfig option being renamed on master (CPU_V7 to CPU_V7A). I changed in Kconfig CUP_V7A to CPU_V7, but still has the same issue. Please look into, thanks.

Comment: Why do you start with some outdated U-Boot? It obviously predates 2016-08-01 because on that day the symbol LINUX\_ARM\_ARCH was replaced by \_\_LINUX\_ARM\_ARCH\_\_. If you want to have chance to get your board into mainline U-Boot start with the current git master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text base of the Beaglebone Black Board is CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE=0x80100000. It is specified in configs/omap3_beagle_defconfig.

The symbol __LINUX_ARM_ARCH__ is defined in arch/arm/Makefile based on CONFIG_SYS_ARM_ARCH which is defined in .config. So something must be wrong with your .config file.

Comment: Thank you a bunch, I will pull the latest and check the config file again.